Is Bitcoin.SE ever going to get out of beta?
It feels like Bitcoin.SE's been in beta forever considering Bitcoin itself is coming up 7 years old now. What's keeping this from launching out of beta? Even Blender.SE is out of beta.

What's keeping this from launching out of beta? http://meta.bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/708/why-is-bitcoin-se-still-in-beta

Thank you, somehow the search wasn't showing it. Must not have picked the right keywords
